# getting text to sit on top of image

Tags: html, css

I have a grid of images that are 3x3. 
What I'd like to be able to do is get text to sit just above each image but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

my CSS

```
 body{background-color:black;}

ul#grid {
  list-style: none;
  width: 1180px;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
   }

#grid li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 70px 0px;
  display:inline;
  position:relative;
   }

#grid li img {
  padding: 15px; margin: 0;
  width: 339px;
  height: 211px;
  position:relative;
   }
```

The HTML

```
<div class="portfolio">
  <ul id="grid">   
    <li><a href="#"><img src="1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="3.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="4.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="5.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="6.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="7.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="8.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="9.jpg"></a></li>
     </ul></div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XYZZx/)

Comment: A tip: `ul#grid` is redundant and leads to some unnecessary searching up the DOM tree. Since each ID can (and *should*) only be used once, you don't need to provide a less-specific selector when you're providing an ID.

Comment: where are the text nodes

Comment: and where are the images (in jsfiddle)?

Comment: This isn't very elegant, but like so: http://jsfiddle.net/jplahn/fCeHb/ (if that's what you want...)

Comment: I'm not sure how to put the text nodes in there. the images are in the jsfiddle

Comment: For your question: I'd wrap each image in a div, then put your text in a div/span/paragraph within that main div, and give that text a higher [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) than the image. If all the images are the same size or the text needs to be in the same spot over all of them, give the wrapping div `position:relative` and the text `position:absolute`, then use top/left/bottom/right to position the text

Comment: And I would likely redesign the layout, but if you really want to keep it that way you can do it as I showed.

Comment: Jordan, how should I redesign the layout?

Comment: @Wantingtolearn use this: http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB04918D7 as inspiration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you meant this: http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/dWuCH/3/

(edited the Fiddle: had some fun :)

```
#grid li span {
    display:block;
    bottom:200px;
    position:relative;
    width:370px;
    margin-left:20px;
}

<div class="portfolio">
    <ul id="grid">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="1.jpg" /><span>Lorizzle ipsizzle shizzlin dizzle hizzle amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing elizzle. </span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="2.jpg" /><span>Lorizzle ipsizzle shizzlin dizzle hizzle amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing elizzle. </span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="3.jpg" /><span>Lorizzle ipsizzle shizzlin dizzle hizzle amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing elizzle. </span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="4.jpg" /><span>Lorizzle ipsizzle shizzlin dizzle hizzle amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing elizzle. </span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="5.jpg" /><span>Lorizzle ipsizzle shizzlin dizzle hizzle amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing elizzle. </span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="6.jpg" /><span>Lorizzle ipsizzle shizzlin dizzle hizzle amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing elizzle. </span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="7.jpg" /><span>Lorizzle ipsizzle shizzlin dizzle hizzle amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing elizzle. </span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="8.jpg" /><span>Lorizzle ipsizzle shizzlin dizzle hizzle amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing elizzle. </span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="9.jpg" /><span>Lorizzle ipsizzle shizzlin dizzle hizzle amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing elizzle. </span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: love the snoop lion psum